# How can be checked the internal state of PHP variables space?

Tags: php

I am preparing for ZCE and currently playing with types, variables. What we know is that variable name can only contain `$`, `_` and alpha-numeric characters, but what about variable variable's names?

Code sample:

```
$v = '12lue';
$b = $$v = 100;

echo $b;
echo $$v;
```

Output:

```
100
100
```

Does it mean that `$$v` also contains value `100` **and its internal name is `12lue` but it can not be accessed directly**?

**UPDATE #1.**

It looks like there are no restrictions on variable variable's names at all:

```
$v = "<";
$b = $$v = 100;
var_dump($$v);
```

Output:

```
int(100)
```

And now I really want to know - does PHP create these variables internally and how can be that proved?

Comment: Weeeeeell… https://3v4l.org/f5Xus

Comment: Whats that @deceze?

Comment: `$ = '';` is also perfectly valid…

Comment: There are icons only. Not variables.

Comment: `$` is a valid variable name…

Comment: `$12lue` is not a valid variable name, from [the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php): "_A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore_"

Comment: @kerbholz, php shows no errors ;) and the question was not about valid / invalid, but about internal state.

Comment: @deceze Is that subliminal for "hands up turd"?

Comment: I guess those rules for variable names are only enforced when parsing PHP code, not when executing it.

Comment: @Andreas  It’s my go-to sample emoji.

Comment: But does it have to be a string? Can you do `$foo = []; $$foo = 'stuff';`?

Comment: $$v can be rewritten to ${$v} and that to ${'12lue'}, and to check it existence,  just var_export get_defined_vars() or array_keys(get_defined_vars())

Comment: Or output `$GLOBALS`

Comment: @FatFreddy, wow! nice function - `get_defined_vars`. It looks like PHP really creates these kind of variables which can be accessed directly from `$GLOBALS`. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Anthony It is converted to string. So your code would create a variable named `$Array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$$v` can be rewritten to `${$v}` and that to `${'12lue'}`, 
and to check for existence, use

http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-defined-vars.php

```
var_export(get_defined_vars())
```

or

```
array_keys(get_defined_vars())
```